# Use a string as a function call scope

Tags: javascript, string, function, scope

```
function foobar() {
    console.log(this);
}

foobar.call("Hello");
```

This code displays :

```
{ '0': 'H', '1': 'e', '2': 'l', '3': 'l', '4': 'o' }
```

I was expecting "Hello" to be displayed.

Why? and how to remedy this?

Comment: first argument of `call` should be an object. So you string type converted to object - `console.log(Object('Hello'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Function#call` is (indirectly) converting the string primitive into a `String` object (see  [§10.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) of the spec; we get there starting from [§15.3.4.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4), which takes us to [§13.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1), which takes us to §10.4.3).

You can force it back with:

```
console.log(this.toString());
```

Note that in strict mode, it wouldn't be converted to a `String` object, because in strict mode, `this` can be a primitive (including a primitive string). E.g.:

```js
// Here, it gets converted to an object
function foo() {
  snippet.log(typeof this); // "object"
}
foo.call("Hello");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

But if we use strict mode:

```js
// Strict mode
"use strict";

// Here, it remains a primitive
function foo() {
  snippet.log(typeof this); // "string"
}
foo.call("Hello");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder — That's a pretty fantastic edit you did while I was stuck in a meeting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the first argument `thisArg` of `call()` function is not `null` or `undefined` so the value of `this` inside function body equals to  `Object(thisArg)`.

Look more in [call function description.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)